# Making a Bland-Altman plot for 2 columns of a data set using R

Tags: r

Can someone help me on this? I would like to make a Bland-Altman plot using R, for 2 columns of my data, the columns are forearm and forearm2 in the data below, but I have no idea how.

```
 > data_2
      Sex Forearm Height Age  Forearm2
1    Male  17    182     55      26
2    Male  18    185    103      28
3    Male  20    171     49      25
4    Male  18    176     58      25
5    Male  21    158     57      23
6  Female  21    155     43      25
7    Male  18    199    114      29
8    Male  19    176     90      25
9    Male  17    191     68      29
10   Male  23    176     52      25
11 Female  19    153     34      24
12 Female  19    160     56      26
13   Male  19    170     47      25
14   Male  22    178     62      25
15 Female  21    174     49      27
16   Male  22    162     40      24
17 Female  23    172     82      27
18 Female  19    185     99      28
19 Female  18    168     66      25
20 Female  17    155     45      24
21   Male  17    182     83      27
22 Female  17    164     42      25
23 Female  18    162     73      26
24   Male  18    185     68      28
25 Female  18    146     50      23
26 Female  23    169     47      25
27 Female  18    160     51      24
28 Female  18    170     69      25
29   Male  24    185     57      27
30   Male  24    167     46      24
31 Female  25    169     47      26
32 Female  24    164     50      25
33 Female  21    155     47     235
34 Female  24    158     37      24
35 Female  23    177     88      27
36 Female  23    155     36      24
37   Male  19    170     47      24
38 Female  21    170     48      26
39 Female  23    160     74      25
40   Male  21    180    100      26
41   Male  19    186     95      27
42   Male  21    181     65      26
```

Here is part of what I have done, but am getting nothing. I saw this on wikipedia, so I tried it out to see what i get.

```
> BAplot=function(data_2$forearm,data_2$forearm2){
  (data_2$forearm,data_2$forearm2,
   xlab="Mean size(mm)", 
   ylab="Difference(mm)",
   ylim=c(15,40),pch=42) 
  abline(0,0)}

Error: unexpected '$' in "BAplot=function(data_2$"
```

Comment: Try to post what you have tried.

Comment: What's a Bland-Altman plot? Show us some effort.

Comment: Two minutes of googling which YOU should have DONE FIRST: http://rstats.tiddlyspot.com/#Bland-Altman

Comment: To do a Bland-Altman plot, objects need to be rated by two different methods each. Then, differences between the methods are plotted against their averages. I can't find any pair of columns in your data that could be compared in such way...

Answer (score 1):

`library(sos); ???altman`  produces :   Packages `MethComp`, `pairedData`, `epade`,`ResearchMethods` , and `mcr` .  The `MethComp` help page warns that the plot command may be deprecated and removed, so I'd grab it while you can :-) or use the other packages.